# Anonymous User initiate WorkFlow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, email, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

I have a sharepoint site that has forms that are accessed by anonymous users. These form save data in a list and when this happens you must trigger a worflow to send a notification email. My question is Anonymous User can trigger worflow?

Answer (score 1):

As you have anonymous site you are using on Prem. So you are using either SP Designer 2010 or 2013 Workflow. If I remember correctly, that WF will trigger under the account you published it. So you need to publish it with account that has the necessary privileges and set it up to trigger when item is created/modified.

Comment: Yes I'm use on Prem, and I Use SP Designer 2010 Workflow, I use a account with the rigths privilegies(I think) to publish the workflow and set the to trigger when created/modified. But when anonymous user created a item the status of workflow remains in "In progress" forever until end up in "Failed on Start (retrying)"